# React / NextJS define Elements ni map

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, foreach, next.js

my problem is this:
I have an array of elements that I want to display with `data.array.map (array => {..}`. But I would like to do it according to a scheme that has different object, like that:

> 1. Element: 3 thirds
> 2. Element: 1 third
> 3. Element: 2 thirds
>    4-5. Element: 1 third
> 4. Element: 2 thirds
>    7, 8. Element: 1 third
> 5. Element: 2 thirds

And it would be nice if this scheme could be continued, i.e. if you could load more objects and then start this scheme all over again.
Is there a way to do this in NextJS? Or a library or something similar?

example picture for the schema:
[image: Schema]

Comment: Bootstrap or Tailwind CSS can help in achieving this layout. E.g. with Bootstrap you can use a sequence of elements with these classes: container row col-12 row col-4 col-8 row col-4 col-4 col-4 row col-8 col-4 row col-4 col-8.

Comment: Thank you, but how is it possible to style each item individually?

Comment: You can use the `for` loop with the step of 10 to iterate over your items and create this 5-row group in each iteration.

Comment: Sorry i dont know how i can make this in react, can you maybe give me a link or a example code snippet?

Comment: Yes, you can look at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-visvesvaraya-m5cw7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: thank you very much you really helped me! :)

Comment: Hey, i have now a other Problem, when i use this Code i get this Error Message:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {__typename, channel}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

ps: when you need a code snippet, this is the file:
https://github.com/Thomas-Blakeney/ArisCorp-Homepage-Frontend/blob/master/src/components/CommLinksSection.jsx

Comment: This link is dead. I get 404 error. If you have another problem I suggest you create a new question and post the code in the question itself.