# NextJS Runtime: "objects are not valid" in a for-loop

Tags: reactjs, next.js, runtime-error

I've already asked a question in which I had the problem that I didn't know how I can create my own layouts for them with a list of objects (similar to data.map) in Next.js. ([React / NextJS define Elements ni map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674642/react-nextjs-define-elements-ni-map?noredirect=1#comment124969105_70674642))

I was then told a solution: (https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-visvesvaraya-m5cw7?file=/src/App.js)

Unfortunately, I now always get an error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
>
> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {__typename, channel}). If you meant to render a collection of
> children, use an array instead.)

I'll link the Git repository and the code snippet below.

Code snippet: https://github.com/Thomas-Blakeney/ArisCorp-Homepage-Frontend/blob/master/src/components/CommLinksSection.jsx

Repo: https://github.com/Thomas-Blakeney/ArisCorp-Homepage-Frontend

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, it's caused by rendering an object directly. The object in question is here:

```
<span className="font-normal text-primary">{channel}</span>
                                            ^
                                            channel is an object
```

This code is present in each `OneThird`, `TwoThirds`, and `ThreeThirds` components.

Looking at the `channel` object it makes sense to render only its `channel` property, so you can change the code to:

```
<span className="font-normal text-primary">{channel.channel}</span>
```

It will show up like this (the red outline is mine):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much, everything works perfectly, I couldn't have done it without you! :)